# How to make Windows Screen Reader (Narrator) to read WinForms Label?

Tags: c#, winforms, accessibility

I'm trying to get the Narrator read my labels in WinForm, but it ignores the label control. Is there a specific way to make it read the label contents? I added description under the properties for "Accessible Description" & "Accessible Name". But no luck.

Since I'm new to the community I was not able to add comment under the already existing question: [How to make JAWS read a simple label?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8174175/how-to-make-jaws-read-a-simple-label?lq=1)

I did a lot of research, only HTML label help is available online and the above thread is more than 3 years old.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Set the AccessibleRole to StaticText and, say, put it in front of a text box.  Once the text box gains focus, Narrator will read it.  What parts of your UI can gain focus are important.

Comment: Thanks @HansPassant! My UI doesn't require a text box or other editable controls since it is a EULA. But as per your suggestion, the narrator reads the label text if I add a text box next to it.

I used an uneditable text box so that the narrator reads to solve my case. If you could put your suggestion in the "Answer" section, I'd like to mark it as an answer. Thanks!